# What does "mod" mean in the context of this tangent space proof in Warner?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I'm trying to read Frank Warner's *Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups* and got confused with Theorem $1.17$ as some who does not have a pure mathematics background.

Let $F_m$ be the set of germs that vanish at $m$ and let $F_m^k$ be the ideal of $\tilde{F}_m,$ the set of germs which vanish at $m,$ consisting of all finite linear combinations of $k$-fold products of elements of $F_m.$

He wishes to show that $\dim (F_m / F_m^2) = \dim M$ and here's how the proof begins:

[image]

I'm good with the first three sentences, but have no idea what he means by the second equation. What does he mean to take the "mod" of that expression? I know that $F_m/F_m^2$ is just a quotient vector space, and I'm certain the "mod" has something to do with that. Also, how does he switch from talking about functions to germs (denoted by boldface)?

Many thanks! I suppose this might be rather obvious if I took an abstract algebra class, but I have not (nor do I have the space in my schedule!).

Comment: I haven't read what you posted super carefully, but "$\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_i(\mathbf{m}) \:\mathrm{mod} F_m^2$" means to consider the class of $\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_i(\mathbf{m})$ in the quotient by $F_m^2$.

Comment: The meaning seems to be that $a=b \mod F_m^2$ if and only the difference $a-b$ belongs to the squared ideal $F_m^2$. The upshot is that all the higher degree terms in the Taylor expansion (such as all multiples of $(x_i-x_i(m))(x_j-x_j(m))$ and hence their sum) belong to $F_m^2$ and can be discarded "modulo $F_m^2$".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you, I got it now! One more question: how do we know $\{\mathbf{x_i-x_i(m)}\}$ spans $F_m/F_m^2?$

Answer (score -2):

Im not fully sure of what it could mean in this context, but as i have experienced it in number theory, a value lets say x, mod m is the remainder after dividing x by m.

As pointer out-by a comment on this post ive realized I have made this an answer and not a comment, as im not fully sure of what “mod” means in this case take my answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: This should perhaps be a comment, not an answer.